# The difference between "avoir ... qui font" and "avoir ... faire"

Tags: constructions

> On n’a pas l'habitude d'**avoir** des gens comme toi aussi haut placés **qui font** un saut chez nous !
>
> {vs}: On n’a pas l'habitude d'**avoir** des gens comme toi aussi haut placés **faire** un saut chez nous !

I wonder if these two different constructions mean more or less the same thing, or do they carry nuances of meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate *aussi haut placés* from the main part of the first sentence:

> *On n’a pas l'habitude d'avoir des gens comme toi, aussi haut placés, qui font un saut chez nous !*

The second sentence is incorrect. It would work with *de voir*:

> *On n’a pas l'habitude de voir des gens comme toi, aussi haut placés, faire un saut chez nous !*

If I keep the core elements, the issue is clearer:

> *On a des gens qui font un saut chez nous.*
>
> <s>*On a des gens faire un saut chez nous.*</s>

Comment: Hi. What do you think about using "faisant"? Or after using the phrase "aussi haut placés", is "qui" the only valid construction? "On n’a pas l'habitude d'avoir des gens aussi haut placés ***faisant*** un saut chez nous !"

Comment: It won't be incorrect but less idiomatic (*on a des gens faisant un saut chez nous.*) unless followed by something like: *On n’a pas l'habitude d'avoir des gens comme toi, aussi haut placés, faisant un saut chez nous à l'improviste !*